# Could not find declaration in function Angular

Tags: angular, file, webstorm, declaration

When I try to declare my audio file WebStorm gives an error it can not find it.

```
audio.src = 'introMusic.mp3';
```

However when I tried it at import it can find it.

```
import {file} from 'introMusic.mp3'
```

Now importing that file is of no use and doesn't work. It's more to show that it is really there.

Why can the file be found in import but in the method it doesn't work? How can I get it to work in the method

Comment: what errors can you see namely? Please share a screenshot

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: doesn't look like the error coming from IDE, rather a runtime one